# div - on mouse move - to left, to right, to up, to down? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, function, mouseevent, mousemove

Is it possible that mouse movement in different directions triggers different actions?

For example, If I move the mouse over div to the left, the div background color gets changed to red. Move to the right - blue bg, up - green, down - black.

So are there events for something like this - events similar to onmouseenter, onmouseleave, onmousemove...?

Or can somebody write a function for this?

**edit:**

```
(function ($) {
    var options = {};
    var oldx = 0;
    var oldy = 0;
    var direction="";
    $.mousedirection = function (opts) {
        var defaults = {
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, opts);
        $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
            var activeElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
            if (e.pageX > oldx && e.pageY > oldy) {
                direction="bottom-right";
            }
            else if (e.pageX > oldx && e.pageY < oldy) {
                direction="top-right";
            }
            else if (e.pageX < oldx && e.pageY < oldy) {
                direction="top-left";
            }
            else if (e.pageX < oldx && e.pageY > oldy) {
                direction="bottom-left";
            }
            else if (e.pageX > oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
                direction="right";
            }
            else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY > oldy) {
                direction="down";
            }
            else if (e.pageX == oldx && e.pageY < oldy) {
                direction="up";
            }
            else if (e.pageX < oldx && e.pageY == oldy) {
                direction="left";
            }
            $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
            $(activeElement).trigger({type:"mousedirection",direction:direction});
            oldx=e.pageX;
            oldy=e.pageY;
        });
    }
})(jQuery)

$(function () {
        $.mousedirection();
        $(".container").bind("mousedirection", function (e) {
            $(this).html(""+e.direction+"");
        });
    });
```

Here is the function that works perfectly (see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/100/ ), but I don't know how to achieve changing div background colors - it currently changes which text is displayed (left, right, etc...) and I don't need any text, I need bg colors.

Can somebody edit this code to achieve this? I tried on my own and I can't get it to work.

**edit2 - solved by making3**

Comment: Use the coordinates in the mousemove event to compute the direction.

Comment: here is the current code: http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/100/
 I need background colors instead of the text. I've tried to edit the code on my own and I can't get it to work. Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://hasin.me/2011/12/20/jquery-mouse-direction-plugin/) plugin looks like what you want.

Comment: this works great! but I need to display background colors, not the text. I've tried to edit the code on my own and I can't get it to work. here is the current code with displaying text in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/100/
can you help me with this?

Comment: All you need to do is set up if statements up for each direction and change the css appropriately. Look at the bottom of the javascript on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/113/) that I modified from your code.

Comment: thank you very much. now the only thing left to do is to make this to work for every div separately (and I have a lot of divs). right now the mouse movement over one div triggers this event on all others with class="container" ( http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/114/ ). Can you set this to work for 100 different classes or ids (container1-100)?

Comment: You should use ids on the divs, and use the id selector instead. [First Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/115/). Or if you want the same actions for all divs (just each separately), you can use `$(this)` instead. [Second Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/116/).

Comment: just one more question - how to achieve that the 1st color you get with mouse movement stays unchanged? I've tried to put onmouseleave="this.mousedirection='null';" but it behaves a little weird and affects every div with the same class.

Comment: Can you place that in a jsFiddle? It sounds like you could place something along the lines of..`onmouseleave="$(this).css('background-color', 'white');" // Set it to the default color`

Comment: it works, but I would need the color you get with the mouse movement to stay, not to restore / get the one specific color.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding. The last fiddle (a few comments up) that I placed, the background-color would stay if you moved outside of the div. Would you mind inserting some sample code at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Yes, I didn't explained well. I mean that if you move the mouse over div again, the color which stayed after leaving the div stays unchanged.

Comment: Essentially, you'll move the mouse in, change the color based on the direction, once you move it back out, it will not change again? [Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/139/). If that's right, you can just unbind the events: `$(".container").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).unbind("mousedirection");
    });`